# Asterisk Answer and Disconnect detection without Tenor gateway

Tags: centos, asterisk, phone-call, agi

I have configured Tenor Aft400 device on my company and i can detect call answering and disconnecting module in itself without any problem. But the problems comes where i have some analog lines and want to use them without any tenor device on my side.I'm looking for a code or configuration to simulate this tenor module in asterisk manually but i don't know how to start. Can anybody give me an approach to get to this goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk not do line detect or anything instead of FXO device.

That is device part.

However it is posible detect something using tonedetect/silencedetect/noise detect, but it require special knoweledge and very high debug experience.

Also possible create custom application based on Fourie Transorm (FFT libs) which will detect frequency of sound and detect condition that way.

To simulate you  can just record calls and use that in recognition soft.

Comment: so what do you think is best way to make those analog line working ? cause for now the analog lines are unused .

Comment: Sorry, there are no easy way do it. Expected cost of such project for person who know how to do is more then $1k. It WILL require complex math and c/c++ programming.

Comment: As option you can check how it realized for chan_dahdi FXO cards, dahdi do all that in software. It use simpler aproximated algorithms, already implemented.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I'm programmer myself. Do you know where is the start point for do programming for this issues ? any reference or article ?

Comment: asterisk source code, file channels/chan_dahdi.c . But note, you need have at least bachalavr degree in mathematic and be familar with FFT to understand logic.